# Is there a canonical dupe target for illegally mutating variables in react?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Every day, multiple times per day, questions pop up in the reactjs tag where the problem boils down to someone

1. Failing to use `this.setState` in a class component and instead trying to use instance properties.
2. Mutating closed-over variables or props in a "pure" functional component instead of using the hooks API.

The necessity of this convention is well-covered in the [official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for [both cases](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), and in the case of pure functional components it's literally *in the name*. Is there a canonical dupe for this? I've searched but either there isn't one or my Google-fu is weak.

## EDIT

I just went ahead and [made one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-correctly/60940634#60940634)

Comment: There is also the ["SO Close Vote Reviewers"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room. It worked for me once in a similar situation.